# Convert date string into date format

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function to get the date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929339/php-function-to-get-the-date-format)

For example:

```
$date = date_parse('2010-09-17 14:00:00');
```

gets me:

```
year    =>  2010
month   =>  9
day     =>  17
hour    =>  14
minute  =>  0
second  =>  0
```

which according to how PHP interpreted the string, corresponds to this format:

`Y-m-d H:i:s`

Given any date string, how can I get the format string, as understood by date_parse / strtotime ?

Comment: So you mean to say you want to report the format string PHP is interpreting?

Comment: yes..............12 more to go omg

Comment: I don't think there's any function that can give you such information; what's the use case?

Comment: Technically `Y-m-d H:i:s` would not be it as `s` is for `00` not just 0, same with the hour, month, and depending on string others as well. The return values of `date_parse()` will not add leading zeroes.

Comment: What would you expect the format for "2012-10-10 10:10:10" to be? That could be `Y-m-d` or `Y-d-m` for the date part, it could be "always 2 digits" for hours or not... fundamentally it's ambiguous. It gets even worse if you allow for 2-digit years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use this way:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2010-09-17 14:00:00'));
```

---

#### Guess date format:

I saw in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1929401) in StackOverflow:

> No, there isn't such a function to guess the date format. You'll need to write a set of regular expression matches which express all the possible variations, e.g.

```
$variations = array (
    '^([0-9]{4})/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{4}2$' => 'Y/m/d H:i:s',
    // more here
);

foreach ($dateFromDatabase as $date) {
    foreach ($variations as $regexp => $dateFormat) {
        if (preg_match ('|' . $regexp . '|', $date)) {
            $matches[$dateFromDatabase] = $dateFormat;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// $matches now consists of an array of dates => format
```

Comment: i dont'want to get the date, I want to get the format :)

Comment: Oh... You wanna detect format from the given way, is it?

Comment: That seems to work for this particular case, but does that regex really cover all date/time formats supported by PHP's date functions?

Comment: @Alex, you would need to make a regex for each possible combination. What exactly are you using this for? We may be able to find a more concrete alternative to achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: well it's for debugging purposes, so its not really that important if there isn't any php function that can provide this info

Comment: We have no clue how PHP's `strtotime` parses the date. ;)